# use empty ID with AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

I use **AUTO_INCREMENT** for my **PK** and I want to reuse ids when I remove a record from the table.

For example, if I delete the record with `id=5`, I want the next insert of a new record to use the empty `id=5`.

So how can I fill the unused IDs with AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: Very bad idea. Re-using primary keys will get you into trouble if you decide to archive your data.

Comment: i will not archive my data :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve anyway? Are you afraid to run out of numbers?

Comment: Yes this is my concern. Run out of numbers

Comment: Are you expecting billions of records?

Comment: Hhh no just i have decare my id as integer

Comment: The maximum value for [`int`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) in MySQL is **2,147,483,647**.  Not enough?

Comment: yes good news but for my question there is any solution just for fun ?

Comment: Use a generated ID. Take a look on the UUID function on mysql. It will generate enough random keys that will allow you to store `N` amount of records without having problems. I'm not sure as to why you want to reuse ID's though. Like they said above, that's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of reusing auto_increments is a horrible idea. Biggest reason for this is concurrency, among others. You can (and will) make your entire database and data model unstable.

Using a proper data type for the id will rectify the issue of you running out of numbers, proper data type being `bigint` in this case.

The `bigint` allows you to store up to the size of 18446744073709551615.

If your inserts are 1000 a second, that means during 1 day you will perform 1000 * 3600 * 24 records, or 86 400 000 records a day. During the course of a year, that will be 31,536,000,000 records. Using simple maths, you can calculate that you'll exceed the `bigint` from above in some 58 000 years if you are able to produce 1000 inserts a second during that time, which should convince you to use proper data types for handling records rather than trying to be smart about that will only result in failure.